# Disable Windows/Home capacitive button programmatically C++

Tags: c++, windows, button, tablet

Surface Pro 3/4 and other Tablets have a physical Windows/Home button.  Microsoft provides an app called "surface" which the user can download and use.  It has a Windows button "off/On" setting to avoid accidental use of the button.
From this it would appear to me that it is possible to turn on/off that button programmatically.   I do not see a Windows call to do it.
Anyone have an experience here in how to sniff what it is they're doing or outright know how to programmatically disable it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Might be more appropriate for the reverse engineering stack exchange. You should probably poke at it and see what functions imports, etc. IDA is very good for this.

Comment: thanks for the response.  Reverse engineering is a avenue if I'm right and there isn't any documentation or knowledge out there on how to do it.  I don't know that I'm right, it may very well be something experts know.